# Laravel: How to get model instance after create that has a global scope

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I struggle to get the model instance with global scopes.

Normally, if you write:

```php
$offer = Offer::createNew();
```

with

```php
public static function createNew()
{
    return static::create([
         'user_id' => auth()->id(), 
         'reviewed' => false
    ]);             
}
```

You would get the model instance. But now I've added a global scope and cannot get it to work.

The model is "nearly" empty as you expect because in my case I want only to get Offers that are reviewed. However, if I add:

```php
public static function createNew()
{
    return static:::withoutGlobalScopes()->create([
         'user_id' => auth()->id(), 
         'reviewed' => false
    ]);             
}
```

I get a result from a limited model that only contains these attributes:

```php
#attributes: array:5 [
    "user_id" => 1
    "reviewed" => false
    "updated_at" => "2018-09-24 11:48:27"
    "created_at" => "2018-09-24 11:48:27"
    "id" => 2
  ]
```

But my model has obviously more attributes than that. If I add get(), I'm only getting

```php
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1635
  #items: []
}
```

So how would you get the model with create when having a global scope?

**Edit**

My first workaround looks like this:

```php
public static function createNew()
{

    $model = static::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(), 
                'reviewed' => false
            ]);

    return static::withoutGlobalScopes()->find($model->id);

}
```

**Edit 2**

My Globalscope looks like this:

```php
class FoodScope implements Scope
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('reviewed', true)
                ->where('paused', false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the global scope.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir updated the post :)

Comment: What is the issue when you use `return static::create([...]);`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir the issue is that I get an empty result, because when the model is returned (and booted), the global scope is applied. So I would love to know how to use create and still get the model instance

Comment: What do you mean by "empty result"? `null`? What's your Laravel version?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thank you for helping me out. I use Laravel 5.6. And with "empty result" you can see it in my post. `#attributes: array:5` You see I get only 5 attributes, but the rest of my 15 attributes are missing because of the global scope

Comment: This has nothing to do with the global scope. Try it without the scope. You can get the other attributes by appending `->fresh()`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir oh wow I'm really confused. I just tested it out and you are right. I was pretty sure that after creating you get the full model instance back with all attributes... Super confused need to to some testing. But with fresh it did work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is not caused by the global scope.

Use `->fresh()` when you want to get the other attributes:

```php
public static function createNew()
{
    return static::create([
         'user_id' => auth()->id(), 
         'reviewed' => false
    ])->fresh();
}
```